# Ubuntu + i3lock lock on lid close

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I looking to lock my laptop when i close the lid and can't get this working in Ubuntu 16.04.

I've tried this https://github.com/ruudud/i3wm-scripts

seems that this is the solution most commonly suggested on the internet, but it does not work.

The github repo suggests creating a service called i3lock.service that runs (as far as i can tell) before "sleep.target". Please note that i have no clue what that is, and would appreciate some more info about that.

I'm not sure if i'm supposed to just create the file and it should work or it requires some special privileges for that file or what? 
More detail on that would be needed.

If this solution is incorrect is it possible to be pointed to a better solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the mean time I switched to Manjaro (much nicer), but this solution should work on both:

Creating a service called `lock@.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=i3lock on suspend
After=sleep.target

[Service]
User=%i
Type=forking
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/locker

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Makeing it executable

```
chmod +x lock@.service
```

Then enableing it for your user

```
systemctl enable lock@<username>.service
```

should do the trick.

Note that the %i in User=%i will be replaced with the `<username>`.
The "/usr/bin/locker" could just be /usr/bin/i3lock but i have some fancy stuff added there to make it look good.

Hope this helps some body at some point

Comment: I can confirm this works on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: "Note that the %i in User=%i will be replaced with the" replaced with the what?

Comment: @dnaik i wrote <username> there without ` around it :P fixed now

Comment: @boogie666 thanks. Could you also share you locker file? I can't figure out how to run this with my lock configurations.

Comment: Works on Fedora 34. Obviously, `ExecStart=/usr/bin/i3lock`, because there's no `locker` executable at `/usr/bin`!

Comment: @dnaik https://pastebin.com/sqkdxna5 here you go
(at the bottom is github link to the version i3lock i use)
But again /usr/bin/locker is just an executable bash file so any locker will work here (like slock from suckless or vanilla i3lock, or whatever)